# Get a certain number of closest coordinates to point (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to extract a defined number (n) of coordinates from unmasked values of an image collection in Google Earth Engine. However, only the closest (n) pixels to a defined point should be selected.

In the code below,

1. I mask a landcover product to get only value for a certain class (30),
2. create an image with with pixels around the focal point (pt),
3. and calculate the distance of the landcover class pixels to the point (dist)

What I want to do next (and where I am stuck):

4. unmask all pixels BUT lets say 1000 with the closest distance
5. turn into a feature collection

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6cdd899f26e1206b9a6b4517d6ebf08

```
var dataset = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019')
.select('discrete_classification');

var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([111.12, 70.02]);
var limits = pt.buffer(50000);

Map.setCenter(111.12, 70.02, 6);

var dist   =  dataset.gt(0).clip(pt.buffer(7500)).mask() // not sure why a buffer is needed
  .updateMask(dataset.select('discrete_classification').eq(30)) // only distances for LC30
  .distance({kernel:ee.Kernel.euclidean(250), skipMasked:true})
  .rename('distance').clip(limits);
var 

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["distance"],
                     "max": 250,
                     "palette":["white", "blue", "red"]};

Map.addLayer(dist, imageVisParam, 'distance');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was definitely an interesting challenge! I think I have a solution. The [link to the code is here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc633c18bd36cf94c946a0ea3591de5e). It consists of the following steps:

1. Rasterize your "point" to get an image. In your code, you used `pt.buffer(7500)` and asked why a buffer is needed. Because a point is infinitesimally small, we definitely need a buffer to rasterize the point. The native scale of the land cover image you are interested in is 100m, so we can use a buffer of 50m -- more on the pixel size later. There might be a better way of doing this step:

```js
  var ptImage = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(pt.buffer(50), {"dummyProperty":1})  
    // You need a buffer because a point is infinitesimally small.
    // Here we use a radius of 50 m.
    ])
  .reduceToImage({
      properties:["dummyProperty"],
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
  });
```

2. Get the distance image. In your code, you used `distance` with `ee.Kernel.euclidean`. I am not sure if this is equivalent, but I went ahead with [fastDistanceTransform](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-fastdistancetransform) instead as inspired by this Q&A: [Forcing GEE's fastDistanceTransform() to operate at specific scale](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408804/forcing-gees-fastdistancetransform-to-operate-at-specific-scale). Since you are interested in only pixels where the land cover is 30, we can add the `.updateMask` as you already have.

```js
  var distance = ptImage
  .unmask(0,false)
  .fastDistanceTransform() 
  .sqrt()
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().sqrt())
  distance = distance.updateMask(distance.lt(maxDist)) //Cutoff distance.
  .updateMask(dataset.eq(30)) // Mask based on discrete_classification=30
```

3. Reduce the distance image to vectors. This is the part that you were missing. I tried two solutions and I will share both of them here, but the `.reduceToVectors` option is definitely the winner.

```js
var distances = distance
.multiply(100).int()  // Scaling the distance here so that the int band is unique for 
// adjacent pixels. 
.rename("int") // this int band will be used to detect homogeneous regions (used for the "labels")
.addBands(distance) // this band will be used by the reducer to assign a property to each feature. 
.reduceToVectors({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.first(),
  geometry: pt.buffer(maxDist), // A circular region centered at your point and extending for r=maxDist.
  crs:exportCrs,
  crsTransform:exportCrsTransform
}).select(["first"],["distance"]) // rename "first" to "distance" and ignore the label assigned by reduceToVectors.
.sort("distance") // Sort the feature collection by ascending distance.
```

This is the alternative -- which worked but was definitely slower, and didn't even compute for the Mercator projection (smaller pixels):

```js
var grid = pt.buffer(maxDist)
.coveringGrid(ee.Projection({crs:exportCrs, transform:exportCrsTransform})) 
//Map.addLayer(grid) 
function getDistanceValue(f){
  return f.set(
    {
    distance:  distance.reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.first(),
      geometry:f.geometry(),
      scale:100
      })
    .get("distance")
    })
}
var distances = ee.FeatureCollection(grid.map(getDistanceValue, true))
.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(["distance"])) 
.sort("distance")
```

A caveat on the pixel size/projection. The point you are interested in is in a very North latitude (70 N). The land cover image's native pixel size is 100m, but on a Mercator (EPSG:3857) projection. The pixels will therefore have a very different size in your location. You have the choice to do the computations using this projection, or change it to a projection that is more suitable for your location, such as [EPSG:32649](https://epsg.io/32649).

The solution will work for both, but the result (e.g. the 10 closest pixels) will be very different:

[image: localProjResult]

The above image is the solution using EPSG:32649

[image: mercatorResult]

The above image is the solution using the original Mercator projection from the land cover image. The pixels are 3 times smaller. To generate this second result, comment out lines 18-21 in the code link shared at the start of the answer.

Comment: This is great, thanks Oliver! Works perfectly if the maximum radius is low and the number of pixels are not too high for the reduceToVectors. However, in my case the search radius can be very large. I was wondering if I could also add a band to the distance image with a sequence from 1 to number of pixels ordered by the distance. Then I can mask all pixels higher the number of points I want, reducing the pixels to turn into polygons (or points with 'centroid') significantly.